# How to detect a connection failure in Indy TCP Client

Tags: c++, c++builder, indy10

I have made a client and a server using Indy `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdTCPServer` in C++Builder 11 Alexandria.

I can start the server and connect the client to it correctly, but if I set the server `MaxConnections` to a value `N` and I try to connect to it with the `N+1` client, the connection does not fail, apparently.

For example: I set `MaxConnections=1` in the server, the first client connects to it and the server `OnConnect` event is raised, while in the client `OnStatus` event I get two messages:

```
message 1: Connecting to 10.0.0.16.
message 2: Connected.
```

I try to connect the second client: the server `OnConnect` event is NOT raised (and this is what I expect) but in the client `OnStatus` event I get the same two messages (and this is not what I expect):

```
message 1: Connecting to 10.0.0.16.
message 2: Connected.
```

Then, the first client can exchange data with the server, and the second client can't (this seems right).

I don't understand why the second client connection does not fail explicitly, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What you describe would make sense for `MaxConnections=1`, not `2`. With `MaxConnections=2`, you should be able to connect and communicate with 2 clients simultaneously

Comment: @Remy - You're right, I have corrected the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. This is **normal behavior** for `TIdTCPServer`.

There is no cross-platform socket API at the OS level <sup>1</sup> to limit the number of *active*/*accepted* connections on a TCP server socket, only to limit the number of pending connections in the server's backlog. That limit is handled by the `TIdTCPServer::ListenQueue` property, which is `15` by default (but this is more of a suggestion than a hard limit, the underlying socket stack can override this, if it wants to).

As such, the `TIdTCPServer::MaxConnections` property is implemented by simply accepting any client from the backlog that attempts to connect, and then *immediately disconnects* that client if the `MaxConnections` limit is exceeded.

So, if you try to connect more clients to `TIdTCPServer` than `MaxConnections` allows, those extra clients will not see any failure in connecting (unless the backlog fills up), but the server will not fire the `OnConnect` event for them. From the clients' perspectives, they actually did connect successfully, they were fully accepted by the server's underlying socket stack (the TCP 3way handshake is complete). However, they simply will not process the disconnect until they try to actually communicate with the server, then they will detect the disconnect, usually in the form of an `EIdConnClosedGracefully` exception (but that is not guaranteed).

<sup>1: on Windows only, there is a `WSAAccept()` function which has a callback that can reject pending connections before they leave the backlog queue. But Indy does not make use of this callback at this time.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I understand better what is going on

Answer (score -1):

Different TCP stacks exhibit different behavior. Your description is consistent with a TCP stack that simply ignores SYNs to a socket that has reached the maximum configured limit of pending and/or accepted connections: the SYN packet is simply dropped on the floor and not acknowledged.

The nature of TCP is that it's supposed to handle network drops. The sender does not immediately bail out, but will keep trying to connect, for some period of time. This part is consistent with all TCP implementations.

If you want your client to quickly fail a connection that does not get established within some set period of time you'll need to implement a manual timeout yourself.

Comment: Thanks Sam for your answer, it is clear. It is a good idea to call TcpClient->Connect() untill I get a EIdAlreadyConnected exception (connection established) or I reach a timeout (connection not established)?

Comment: Whether something is a "good idea" or not depends entirely on what you want to do. You should get a clear indication, from each call, whether the connection succeeded. If it did, then it doesn't really make much sense to call it again, in order to just throw an exception. Your connection has been established.

Comment: This answer has good information, but is not what is happening in this particular situation. This answer is describing what happens when the server backlog fills up with pending connections. See my answer for an alternative explanation.